# .NET file deletion

Tags: c#

In my c# application , i am facing an issue with `File.Delete()`. I will brief my issue below.

I am running Station and Server,Station is windows appln and Server is console.Here i am using sqlite db.so in station front end we have a button clean db. when i click on this i have to delete db and start new sync.means request send from station to server and server respond back.but issue is that when i click clean db it says file is used by other process which is server.without closing server i need to delete the db. please give me solution.

Comment: You can't delete files that are in use by another process. It's simply not possible. You'll need to find another way. It's not clear why you can't just close the database connection on the server.

Comment: Is the database opened from both client *and* server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any luck deleting file being used by console (`server`) application. You should communicate your intent to `console` app, which will then close file, delete it and lets the client know the outcome. Then your client can initiate sync procedure.